# ROS Error: Cannot Launch Node of Type

Tags: roslaunch, rosnode, catkin, package.xml, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am running Ubuntu 14.04. I've successfully installed ROS Indigo. There is this open source program called ORB-SLAM that I am trying to run but I getting an error.

Instructions I am following:

- In Terminal 1:   `roscore`
- In Terminal 2:   `roslaunch ExampleGroovyHydro.launch`
- In Terminal 3:   `rosbag play --pause Example/ Example.bag`

Wait for Terminal 2 to finish loading the vocabulary file, then press “space” in terminal 3.

The error that I am getting:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [ORB_SLAM/ORB_SLAM]: ORB_SLAM
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/ria/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

(Note: I am guessing this is coming from my `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`)

What's inside the launch file:

```
<launch>
   <node pkg="image_view" type="image_view" name="image_view" respawn="false" output="log">
    <remap from="/image" to="/ORB_SLAM/Frame" />
    <param name="autosize" value="true"/>
   </node>
   <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d $/home/ria/ORB_SLAM/Data/rviz.rviz" output="log">
   </node>
   <node pkg="ORB_SLAM" type="ORB_SLAM" name="ORB_SLAM"  args="Data/ORBvoc.yml Data/Settings.yaml" cwd="node" output="screen">
   </node>
</launch>
```

I am fairly new to ROS so I have a few questions:

1. I found a ROS link to install a catkin workspace. I've installed a workspace in the folder `catkin_ws`. This is a folder in my parent directory. It's not in my project folder. Am I supposed to have the workspace in my project folder?
   (Note: I think I might have installed a workspace from the source instead of using the pre-existing one provided by ROS. That's because I didn't know how to use/run/install the pre-existing workspace. I would like to know how to do this.)
2. My `catkin_ws` folder doesn't have a `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt` in its folder. I found a `CMakeLists.txt` but that's in its `src` folder. I found both these files inside 'Beginner's tutorial' folder. Where are these supposed to be? Did I install the workspace incorrectly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213824/ros-error:-cannot-launch-node-of-type/) by [madeye](https://answers.ros.org/users/23200/madeye/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2015-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wasn't using a workspace properly. I was able to run the ORB_SLAM package by following these instructions by jwcrawley on github: https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM/issues/39

jwcrawley commented 13 days ago
Greetings @riaverma96 ,

That was an annoying error I kept getting, but I think I've solved it now. I'll start from the beginning, which seems to have worked on 2 separate machines:

(Be aware, I only recommend the 1st step for completely clean install)

1. Use Synaptic and completely remove ALL ros packages
2. Follow steps on http://www.ros.org/install/ for Desktop-Full Install. I've used Jade.
3. Go into your ~/.bashrc and remove all instances of ROS (should be a source and an export line)
4. At the bottom of the ~/.bashrc, you want to put the following:
   source /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash
   export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/catkin_ws:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
5. Get ORB_SLAM into your ~/catkin_ws directory va git. After this is done, you'll have ~/catkin_ws/ORB_SLAM/{stuff}
6. Edit ORB_SLAM/manifest.xml and remove the whole line that mentions opencv2
7. Follow the compile directions appropriately for 3rd party and then main.
8. Add a node to the ExampleGroovyHydro.launch at the top (beneath the )

   ```
       <node name="usb_cam" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
               <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video0" />
               <param name="image_width" value="640" />
               <param name="image_height" value="480" />
               <param name="pixel_format" value="mjpeg" />
               <param name="camera_frame_id" value="usb_cam" />
               <param name="io_method" value="mmap"/>
       </node>
   ```

9: Run roscore in a terminal.

10: Now use roslaunch to launch that file. It should spin up rviz and a webcam viewer.
Should be up and running.

---

Originally posted by [madeye](https://answers.ros.org/users/23200/madeye/) with karma: 36 on 2015-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kathir](https://answers.ros.org/users/28902/kathir/) on 2017-02-03**:
Hi madeye, If i have to implement this ORB_SLAM in ARDRONE, which are the parameter do I have to change ??? there is launch file for ARDrone  like ardrone.launch. so which launch file should I run to get 3D visualization of the environment ?  should i use both launch files ??

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error you are getting is referring to this line:

```
 <node pkg="ORB_SLAM" type="ORB_SLAM" name="ORB_SLAM"  args="Data/ORBvoc.yml Data/Settings.yaml" cwd="node" output="screen">
```

This means that `roslaunch` cannot find the executable file `ORB_SLAM` anywhere in the `ORB_SLAM` package. Now, it's not clear to me why that's the case, but a common issue is that users do not source the `setup.bash` file after building which allows tools like `roslaunch` to find things like this. So presumably you built the workspace containing `ORB_SLAM` and that would have generated this `setup.bash` file somewhere. But without more information on how you built or installed this package you want to use, it's hard to help you further.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-07-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1